# How to re-apply earlier commits after git soft reset?

Tags: git

I had `git reset --soft` our codebase back 24 hours. During this time, about 30 PRs got merged. Now we need re-create those PRs one by one. How do extract raw changes from earlier PRs so I could re-apply them?

For context, `git cherry-pick` is not going to work, since these commits are already merged.

Comment: Git does not have pull requests. *GitHub* and *Bitbucket* do both have pull requests, but they do them slightly differently, and it's easy enough to find at least the GitHub ones to redo them. But you don't say whether you're using GitHub or Bitbucket. (Note that GitLab have Merge Requests instead of Pull Requests.) Update your tags and/or provide additional information in your question. I'll also note that cherry-pick *will* work and that `--soft` retains uncommitted work, so there's something *else* missing from this question too.

Comment: When you "I had `git reset --soft` our codebase ...", do you mean your master branch was at commit `A`, and that you used `git reset --soft ...` followed by `git commit` to create a commit `A'` with *exactly the same content*, but a shorter history ?

Comment: I think you need to say why you did a reset. Because without context the obvious answer is to reset forward to after all the PRs you want to keep. (For example, are you trying to pull out a single PR from 24 hours ago? If yes, why couldn't you simply revert that PR?) And, why don't you think cherry-pick will work? Did you try it?

Comment: BTW, the last sentence is confusing, specifically, "...since these commits are already merged." Doing a reset implies you are going to force push when you're done, and when you do, those commits will no longer be merged.

Comment: @TTT soft reset does require force push. I used soft reset to create a commit that reverts changes of the last 24 hours.

Comment: can you please describe what you did *after* `git reset --soft` ? did you `git commit` right afterwards ? unstage some changes ? edited some files ? ...